# MongoDB misuses GeoSpatialIndexes within CompoundIndexes when sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, multi-index

I go to the Mongo command line (version 4.4.1) and do

```
db.places.dropIndexes()
db.places.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" , category1 : 1 } )
db.places.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" , category2 : 1 } )

db.places.find({ location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 0, 0 ] } } } }).sort({ category2  : 1 }).explain()
```

The result shows that the index (location, category2) is not used, event though there is a perfect match for the query (find by location and sort by category2).
The winning plan shows the category1 index is used:
**"indexName" : "location_2dsphere_category1_1",**

```
 db.places.find({ location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 0, 0 ] } } } }).sort({ category2  : 1 }).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "dev.places",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "location" : {
                "$near" : {
                    "$geometry" : {
                        "type" : "Point",
                        "coordinates" : [
                            0,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "queryHash" : "8766F2A3",
        "planCacheKey" : "9B5661A5",
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "category2" : 1
            },
            "memLimit" : 104857600,
            "type" : "simple",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "GEO_NEAR_2DSPHERE",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "location" : "2dsphere",
                    "category1" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "location_2dsphere_category1_1",
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "location" : "2dsphere",
                            "category1" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "location_2dsphere_category1_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "location" : [ ],
                            "category1" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "location" : [
                                "[-9223372036854775807, -6917529027641081857]",
                                "[-6917529027641081855, -4611686018427387905]",
                                "[1, 2305843009213693951]",
                                "[2305843009213693953, 4611686018427387903]",
                                "[4611686018427387905, 6917529027641081855]",
                                "[6917529027641081857, 9223372036854775807]"
                            ],
                            "category1" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "category2" : 1
                },
                "memLimit" : 104857600,
                "type" : "simple",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "GEO_NEAR_2DSPHERE",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "location" : "2dsphere",
                        "category2" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "location_2dsphere_category2_1",
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "location" : "2dsphere",
                                "category2" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "location_2dsphere_category2_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "location" : [ ],
                                "category2" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "location" : [
                                    "[-9223372036854775807, -6917529027641081857]",
                                    "[-6917529027641081855, -4611686018427387905]",
                                    "[1, 2305843009213693951]",
                                    "[2305843009213693953, 4611686018427387903]",
                                    "[4611686018427387905, 6917529027641081855]",
                                    "[6917529027641081857, 9223372036854775807]"
                                ],
                                "category2" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "XXXX",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.1",
        "gitVersion" : "ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**"winningPlan" : {**
"stage" : "SORT",
"sortPattern" : {
"category2" : 1
},
"memLimit" : 104857600,
"type" : "simple",
"inputStage" : {
"stage" : "GEO_NEAR_2DSPHERE",
"keyPattern" : {
"location" : "2dsphere",
"category1" : 1
},
**"indexName" : "location_2dsphere_category1_1",**

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2020/05/16/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes-the-equality-sort-range-esr-rule/.

$near is a range query and the index must reference the field being sorted on before fields that have range conditions on them to satisfy both range and sort requirements.

Neither of your indexes can be used to sort your query. MongoDB picks the first one since the usable part of them is just the geo index.

Since you haven't specified a distance with $near you are probably getting all documents that have the location field set via the index scan.

Comment: So how can I do it then? I just need to find by location and sort by category2. I tried creating indexes the other way around, for example ```db.places.createIndex( { category2: 1,  location : "2dsphere" } )```, but then I get the error NoQueryExecutionPlans

Comment: The full error is:
```
Error: explain failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=dev.placesTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: { category2: 1.0 }\nProj: {}\n planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query",
 "code" : 291,
 "codeName" : "NoQueryExecutionPlans"
} :
```

Comment: Additionally, If, because of that error, I add a single index in location, then when performing the original request "find by location, sort by category2" will use the single index for location, ignoring the compound index (category2, location).

Comment: Using a normal index (not 2dsphere) then the range index work are expected and explained in the link you posted. Yet 2dsphere indexes do not act as proper index for range search (geolocation search). Any clues?

Comment: I think you are always going to have a sort stage after using a geo index in the described query.

Comment: How this answer the comments I made? The compound index {category2, location} is never used because: 1) A location as geospehere needs an index itself (otherwise I get the "unable to find index for $geoNear query"
2) If I add the index for location, to shut up the error, the that single index is used, eveny though {category2, location} index should be used.

Comment: geo index must be the first one in a compound index, so (category, location) index is not going to be used by anything.

Comment: that is what I originally tried and the whole question was about. Then was your comment about having a Sort before a Range in the index (your link).

Comment: What you want cannot be done as far as I know.

Comment: @D.SM "geo index must be the first one in a compound index" that's not correct. from mongo docs: "Unlike the 2d index, a compound 2dsphere index does not require the location field to be the first field indexed"